# When running a command on a file, is there any way to reference the file without typing the entire name?

Tags: bash

For example:

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz ;  rm test.tar.gz
```

Is there a faster way to reference the file name on the second execution?

I was thinking something like this (which is invalid):

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz ; rm $1
```

Anything possible?

I'm fully aware of wildcards.

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139202/reuse-similar-flags-for-multiple-commands, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136599/run-two-commands-on-one-argument-without-scripting

Answer (score 19):

You could assign the filename to a variable first:

```
f=test.tar.gz; tar xvf "$f"; rm "$f"
```

Or use the [`$_` special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters), it contains the last word of the previous command, which is often (but of course not always) the filename you've been working with:

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz; rm "$_"
```

This works with multiple commands too, as long as the filename is always the last argument to the commands (e.g. `echo foo; echo $_; echo $_` prints three times `foo`.)

As an aside, you may want to consider using `tar ... && rm ...`, i.e. with the `&&` operator instead of a semicolon. That way, the `rm` will not run if the first command fails.

Comment: Loved “$_” didn’t knew about it! Thanks a lot for your contribution, well put!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `!$` if you move the second command to a new line.

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz
rm !$
```

Comment: What does it do in general? Is it similar to `$_`?

Comment: it inserts last  argument from last command in history.

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `!$` and `$_` is?

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`  version above 4, you can use history expansion to reference the nth positional parameter of the current command. For instance, in `tar xvf test.tar.gz` that is 2nd positional parameter to the command, thus the command can be reduced to

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz && rm !#:2
```

Another, more portable way ( tested with `/bin/dash` ) is to use `$_` variable to reference *last* positional parameter:

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz && rm "$_"
```

See also 
[How do I execute multiple commands using the same argument?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1048295/295286)

Answer (score 0):

if you ever used a loop to process multiple files, then you were already using a way that you can also use for just one file:

```
for i in a.tgz b.tgz c.tgz; do tar xvf $i; rm $i; done
```

for one file:

```
for i in a.tgz; do tar xvf $i; rm $i; done
```

i find this solution noteworthy because this for loop is a common pattern that you may already be using, but have not thought to apply to this question. it didn't come to my mind either when i initially thought it.